# What does `!(error_reporting() & $errorcode)` do (PHP)?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm trying to write my own error-reporting function. As a template I'm using an example that contains this code snippet:

```
if (!(error_reporting() & $errorcode)) {
    return;
}
```

But what does it exactly do? I can't understand for what the ampersand is between `error_reporting()` & `$errorcode` (`errorcode` is a function-parameter).
I tried to output `error_reporting()` and I got this (seems like it was called multiple):

```
int(32767)
Unknown errortype: [8] Undefined variable: kj
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
int(0)
```

I searched then at [php.net](http://php.net) and saw that `32767` is the error `E_ALL`, but it says in the line below the error code is `8`, which is an `E_NOTICE`-error?!
I'm overwhelmed and I am unable to understand is. Does someone is able to explain this behaviour detailed?

Comment: The `&` operator is a bitwise AND operator. Check them on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Trivia: `?` is question mark. `&` is an [ampersand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yeah, sorry, I meant that. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

This block will return immediately if error reporting is explicitly disabled. You don't want your error reporting to get invoked when the code creating the error disabled error reporting.